# Unresolved reference: adapter in RecyclerviewFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm currently trying to implement editing items in Recyclerview on imageView click in a single Recyclerview row, but I can't figure out how to solve the reference for adapter outside of onCreateView in a fragment. How do I fix this issue and get rid of the error? What is the cause of this problem?

RecyclerviewFragment.kt:

```
class RecyclerviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel
    private lateinit var viewHolder: ViewHolder

    private var _binding: FragmentRecyclerviewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

        val adapter = ListAdapter{showUpdateDialog()}
        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // Creates a controller responsible for swiping and moving the views in recyclerview
        val itemTouchController = ItemTouchHelper(
            object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: ViewHolder, target: ViewHolder,
                ): Boolean {
                    // Move specific item from "fromPos" to "toPos" in recyclerview adapter
                    val fromPos = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
                    val toPos = target.bindingAdapterPosition
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos)
                    return true // true if moved, false otherwise

                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    mUserViewModel.deleteUser(adapter.getTaskPosition(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition))
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Task deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
            })

        itemTouchController.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)

        mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun updateItemInDatabase(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        val editText = (dialog as AlertDialog).findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
        val task = editText?.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(task)) {
            // Update an entity
            mUserViewModel.updateUser(adapter.getTaskPosition(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Task updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill out required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun inputCheck(task: String): Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(task))
    }

    private fun showUpdateDialog() {
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setView(R.layout.fragment_add)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to negative button press
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.cancelled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialogInterface, _ ->
                    // Respond to positive button press
                    updateItemInDatabase(dialogInterface)
                }
                .show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you require a global reference to your adapter? Where exactly do you want to use the adapter? If thats the case then declare your adapter above `onCreateView` as

```
private lateinit var adapter
```

then on your `onCreateView` initialise the adapter as

```
adapter = ListAdapter{showUpdateDialog()}
```

You can then use the adapter reference anywhere you want on that class